# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. 405

Tags: ajax, laravel, api, laravel-8

My Laravel API is hosted on godaddy and I am call that API from localhost. Here is

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.com/api/ali',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        image: dataURL,
        patientname: $('.patientname').attr('patientname'),
        phone: phonenum,
        mrid: $('.patientmrid').attr('mrid'),
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $(".btnsave").text('Send message');
        if(response == "success"){
            $('.alert-success').fadeIn(300).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
        }else if(response == "notsaved"){
            $('.alert-danger').fadeIn(300).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
        }else if(response == "notsent"){
            $('.alert-danger').fadeIn(300).delay(50000).fadeOut(1000);
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        $('.alert-danger').fadeIn(300).delay(50000).fadeOut(1000);
    }
});
```

Following is my code of API hosted on different domain

```
Route::post('/ali', function(Request $request) {

$img = $request->image;
$mrid = $request->mrid;
$phone = $request->phone;
$patientname = $request->patientname;

// my code

if(str_starts_with($response, 'OK')){
    if($success){
        return "success";
    }else{
        return "notsaved";
    }
}else{
    return "notsent";
}

});
```

I have ssl certificate installed on my godaddy domain. When I call this API using 40% of the time I get successful response and 60% of the time I get status code 405, even if I send exact same data. If there was a problem then why it's not showing me error all the time? I have tried all possible solution on internet related to this error.

Comment: are you pass csrf token in your request?

Comment: I tried it. Read it from Laravel documentation. headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }

Comment: Maybe I need to clear my route cache after I pass token